# how to access GetMapping notation from postman with HttpServletRequest

Tags: spring, servlets, postman

I have a spring boot controller but I don't know how to access the GetMapping notation through postman application. This is my controller:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<dataTableDTO> getProject(HttpServletRequest request, int draw) throws Exception  {
        //... do what needs to be done

    List<ProjectEntity> objProj = (List<ProjectEntity>) projectRepository.findAll();

    List<String> slist = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(ProjectEntity d : (List<ProjectEntity>)objProj){
        slist.add(String.valueOf(d.getCustomerId()));
    }
    String listCustId = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(slist);

    List<CustomerDTO> objCust = (new CustomerDAO()).getCustomer(listCustId, request.getHeader("Authorization"));

    List<ProjectDTO> objProjDTO = new ArrayList<ProjectDTO>();

    for(ProjectEntity d : (List<ProjectEntity>)objProj){
        String name = "";
        for(CustomerDTO c : objCust){
            if(c.getId() == d.getCustomerId()){
                name = c.getFirstName() + " " + c.getLastName();
            }
        }

        objProjDTO.add(new ProjectDTO(d.getId(), d.getCustomerId(), name, d.getName(), d.getType()));
    }

    dataTableDTO data = new dataTableDTO(draw, objProjDTO.size(), objProjDTO.size(), objProjDTO, null);

    return new ResponseEntity<dataTableDTO>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I just want to know how to access the GetMapping notation through postman. I already try but i got error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hvZ.png)

Comment: URL is correct, I think it an exception in the business logic of your code. Try to debug the code.

Comment: Just try to replace @GetMapping with @GetMapping("/")

Comment: still got error

Comment: I think it issue in code, not with mapping ..probably you need to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

Put a @RequestParam annotation on your draw variable?

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<dataTableDTO> getProject(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(name="draw") int draw) throws Exception  {...}
```